# Continuations/Coroutines/Generators in C++ / gcc / linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, coroutine

**Background:** I'm trying to figure out how to implement continuations/coroutines/generators (whatever the following is called) by posing this toy problem.  The environment is C++11 on gcc 4.6 and linux 3.0 x86_64.  Non-portable is fine but using an external library (boost.coroutine, COROUTINE, etc) is not allowed.  I think `longjmp(3)` and/or `makecontext(2)` and friends may help but not sure.

**Description:**

The following toy parser is supposed to parse sequences of as and bs of equal length. ie

```
((a+)(b+))+
```

such that the length of the second bracketed production equals the third.

When it finds a production (eg aaabbb) it outputs the number of `a`s it finds (eg 3).

**Code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char* s;

void yield()
{
        // TODO: no data, return from produce
        abort();
}

void advance()
{
        s++;
        if (*s == 0)
                yield();
}

void consume()
{
        while (true)
        {
                int i = 0;

                while (*s == 'a')
                {
                        i++;
                        advance();
                }

                cout << i << " ";

                while (i-- > 0)
                {
                    if (*s != 'b')
                        abort();
                    advance();
                }
        }
}

void produce(const char* s_)
{
        s = s_;

        // TODO: data available, continue into consume()
        consume();
}

int main()
{
        produce("aaab");
        produce("bba");
        produce("baa");
        produce("aabbb");
        produce("b");

        // should print: 3 1 4

        return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**

As you can see the state of the `consume` call stack must be saved when `yield` is called and then `produce` returns.  When `produce` is called again, `consume` must be restarted by returning from `yield`.  The challenge would be to modify the way `produce` calls `consume`, and implement `yield` so they function as intended.

(Obviously reimplementing consume so that it saves and rebuilds its state defeats the purpose of the exercise.)

I think what needs to be done is something like the example on the bottom of the makecontext man page: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/makecontext.3.html, but its not clear how to translate it onto this problem. (and I need sleep)

**Solution:**

(Thanks to Chris Dodd for design)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ucontext.h>
using namespace std;

const char* s;
ucontext_t main_context, consume_context;

void yield()
{
    swapcontext(&consume_context, &main_context);
}

void advance()
{
    s++;
    if (*s == 0)
            yield();
}

void consume()
{
    while (true)
    {
            int i = 0;

            while (*s == 'a')
            {
                    i++;
                    advance();
            }

            cout << i << " ";

            while (i-- > 0)
            {
                    advance();
            }
    }
}

void produce(const char* s_)
{
    s = s_;

    swapcontext(&main_context, &consume_context);
}

int main()
{
    char consume_stack[4096];

    getcontext(&consume_context);
    consume_context.uc_stack.ss_sp = consume_stack;
    consume_context.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(consume_stack);
    makecontext(&consume_context, consume, 0);

    produce("aaab");
    produce("bba");
    produce("baa");
    produce("aabbb");
    produce("b");

    // should print: 3 1 4

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `longjmp`?  I'm not aware of any function spelled `longjump`.

Comment: makecontext is deprecated iirc.

Comment: Why do you think makecontext is deprecated?  It doesn't say anything about it on the man page?

Comment: Oh here it is: "SUSv2,  POSIX.1-2001.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specifications of makecontext() and swap‐context(), citing portability issues, and recommending that applications be rewritten  to use POSIX threads instead."  POSIX threads are preemptive though, creating a whole new cloned process, I think userland cooperative threads will be more performant for this type of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its fairly straight-forward to use makecontext/swapcontext for this -- you use makecontext to create a new coroutine context and swapcontext to swap between them.  In you case, you need one additional coroutine to run the `consume` infinite loop, and you run main and produce in the main context.

So `main` should call getcontext+makecontext to create a new context that will run the consume loop:

```
getcontext(&consume_ctxt);
// set up stack in consume_context
makecontext(&consume_ctxt, consume, 0);
```

and then `produce` will switch to it instead of calling `consume` directly:

```
void produce(const char* s_)
{
    s = s_; 
    swapcontext(&main_ctxt, &consume_ctxt);
}
```

and finally `yield` just calls `swapcontext(&consume_ctxt, &main_ctxt);` to switch back to the main context (which will continue in `produce` and immediately return).

Note that since `consume` is an infinite loop, you don't need to worry too much about what happens when it returns (so the link will never be used)